# How do I reset a rospy Timer?

Tags: rospy, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I reset a rospy Timer? I want to have a Python node that sends out a message like `cmd_vel` as a step function to test a controller, but I also want to use dynamic reconfigure to be able to change the dt for when the step function should increase. For example, I would like to do one run where my velocities increase by the step amount every 1 second, then do a second run where my velocities increase by the step amount every 5 seconds. I want to use the exact same callback function for modifying the `cmd_vel` output message but I want that callback function to be invoked at different times. The code I have so far that does *not* work is

```
def reset_timers(self):
    try:
        del self.output
    except AttributeError:
        rospy.loginfo("self.output exception caught")
    self.output = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(self.output_dt), self.output_callback)
```

Note that the function `reset_timers` is called when the Python class is initialized and whenever `self.output_dt` is modified by dynamic reconfigure.

The behavior I see when using this code is that the timers are additive. Using the previous example, if I change dt from 1 second to 5 seconds, then the timer goes to the callback function every 1 second *and* every 5 seconds. If I modify `self.output_dt` often enough then each one of those times is used to invoke the callback and I end up outputting a new message with an increased velocity very rapidly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71917/how-do-i-reset-a-rospy-timer?/) by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4347 on 2013-08-08

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Time it says

> To stop the Timer from firing, call shutdown().

I did not check if it works, so sorry if I'm wrong.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2013-08-12**:
That was exactly the right answer and my output looks the way that I want it to now. Thanks @BennyRe! Should this be part of the documentation at: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/rospy/html/rospy.timer-module.html?